# Can someone help me understand line for line what is going on in the render method of this code?

Tags: java, multithreading, rendering, buffer

I also don't entirely understand what volatile and synchronized modifiers do. but basically this is supposed to be well the beginnings  of a game that im learning from a youtube series and all it does so far is start a thread that has a while loop that inside run through the methods update and render. Thing is i don's understand anything in the render  method besides the setting of the color and creation of the rectangle.

```
package game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game implements Runnable {

    public static Thread Game;
    public volatile boolean running = false;

    public void start() {
        running = true;
        Game = new Thread(this);
        Game.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        running = false;
        try {
            Game.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("asddsa");
        }

    }

    public void update() {

    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = GameFrame.GraphicsBoard.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            GameFrame.GraphicsBoard.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GameFrame.GraphicsBoard.getWidth(),
                GameFrame.GraphicsBoard.getHeight());
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        new GameFrame();

        while (running) {
            update();
            render();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I suggest you re-write the code so it only includes things you understand.  As far as I can see, half the code isn't needed or is wrong, so I cannot explain it to you.

Comment: Maybe you would like to start with a more basic example? Graphics and synchronization are not the best friends of a newbie.

Comment: The thing is its part of a tutorial that i'm learning off of YouTube and the way the guy who explained it didn't explain it very well

Comment: That's the problem with random tutorials on Youtube. I suggest you choose a more reliable source, like the official Oracle Java tutorials. I would immediately reject a tutorial that doesn't even respect the standard Java naming conventions.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on where to go for game programming I taught myself the basics with  'Head First Java'  should i go into more intermediate java tutorials or do you think with the amount you learn from that book I can go into game programming tutorials.

Comment: Start with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html. Also read the javadoc of javax.swing.Timer. I'm not really into games, so I don't know about tutorials about games. But this will at least tell you the basics about threads and threads in Swing.

Answer (score 2):

***Volatile***

Volatile in Java is used as an indicator to Java compiler and  Thread that do not cache value of this variable and always read it from main memory.

In this code example One Thread (Game Thread) can cache the value of "*running*" instead of getting it from main memory every time and if in between any other thread changes the value; it would not be visible to this thread. Making boolean variable "*running*" as volatile in java ensures this case not happen.

[***Synchronized***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

Synchronized is used to make your methods thread safe.

*Edit*: Long answer as below.

If your code is executing in multi-threaded environment you need synchronization for objects which are shared among multiple threads to avoid any corruption of state or any kind of unexpected behaviour.

synchronized keyword in java provides locking which ensures mutual exclusive access of shared resource and prevent data race. Also thread needs to acquire a lock before accessing the piece of code which is synchronised.

Synchronization can done for the whole method or a particular block. The example shows method synchronisation. Means the whole method is locked and at any point of time only one thread can access your method.

Method synchronisation is not advised because it may reduce performance. There are other pros and cons which am not covering in this reply.

Comment: @JBNizet yup agreed. Its a bad idea to synchronize your whole methods. But am just answering to OP why the keyword is used there.

Comment: @JayamohanThanks for the input but why would synchronizing the whole method be a bad thing?

Comment: The problem is not synchronizing the whole method. The problem is saying that synchronizing a method makes it magically thread-safe. It doesn't. It just makes it synchronized. You should explain what synchronization actually does.

Comment: That would be very helpful if you could!

Comment: Only one `synchronized` method may be running per object at any given time (this is achieved through a hidden lock inside the object). Therefore, if two threads call two `synchronized` methods on the same object at about the same time, the "second" thread will block before entering the `synchronized` method, until the "first" thread has gotten out of its own `synchronized` method. (I hope it makes sense written like this.)

Comment: @XSoloDolo check the updated reply

Comment: Thanks for the reply really helps so basically what your saying is a synchronized method or block code can only be accessed by one thread at a time which would cause errors if im using multiple threads that are trying to access said method or block of code.

Comment: @XSoloDolo: no, it would not cause an error. If a thread already has the lock, another thread wanting to acquire it will wait until the lock is released.